# WCF configuration setting information at a glance

Tags: wcf

Is there any site from where I can get the most of the information about WCF configuration settings e.g. `keyEntropyMode`,`maxStatefulNegotiations`,`sessionKeyRolloverInterval`, `negotiationTimeout` etc.

I have started recently working in wcf but is facing many troubles in understanding the terms. There are to be honest huge. And whenever I get stuck, it takes a long time for me to solve it (searching and searching in google and after spending sometime hours I may get the solution).

Henceforth, I think it is better to know if not all astleast some of the terms and their usage and what they means.

It would be great help if anyone can point such a link. I searched in the net with **" wcf configuration file elements"** but with not much luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be a very very large page! All the WCF settings..... don't know if you could have that "at a glance"....

WCF is a big beast - it has a ton of options and settings, and they do get almost overwhelming. Point is: do not try to know and master all of them - you won't be able to do that. Get to know what you need to know, build a solid foundation, and then go from there and learn more as you need to.

Also - do you know about the visual WCF Service Config Tool in Visual Studio?? Extremely helpful indeed! Invoke it from the `Tools > WCF Service Configuration Editor` menu or right-click on a app.config in your solution explorer and pick `Edit WCF Configuration`. You'll get something like this:

[image]

The great thing about this is:

- it gives you dropdown lists for lots of stuff, like the bindings - you can pick your binding, so you always see your valid options
- it will show you the properties on each item, so you can fill them out as needed (or even discover new properties)
- it gives you nice tasks you can perform, like adding a new service or a new endpoint

That's probably as close as it gets to a "complete overview" of WCF. Other than that - check out the great books [Learning WCF](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596101627) by Michele Leroux Bustamante for intro to intermediate level, and [Programming WCF Services](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596521308) by Juval Lowy for really advanced stuff. Great references and great places to look up stuff!

[Learning WCF http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41wYa%2BNiPML._BO2,204,203,200_PIsitb-sticker-arrow-click,TopRight,35,-76_AA240_SH20_OU01_.jpg](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41wYa%2BNiPML._BO2,204,203,200_PIsitb-sticker-arrow-click,TopRight,35,-76_AA240_SH20_OU01_.jpg)

[image: Programming WCF Services]

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what problem are you trying to solve?  You don't really need to learn all WCF config settings.  There are a lot of settings, some are specific to hosting methods, concurrency (or lack thereof), session management, instancing, bindings, behaviors, etc...

Comment: You are right sir... but i want to get my self familiar with those. And regarding problem, there are not specific.. every time i encounter a new prob.  As i said I have just started.. henceforth want to know it as much as possible but with time.

Comment: You should stop before you start. It is a **bad** idea to try to learn the configuration settings. Instead, learn how WCF works. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/wcf and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/dd939784.aspx.